# Linking to External Stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

Background: For the website I am on (a roleplay forum) you are allowed to use custom css and html in posts. To do this, you have to use a [dohtml] BBCode tag. Then you can insert any css/html you wish.

Problem: Some users have used linked stylesheets to make theirs show up. And it works. But mine doesn't.

Other: I am unable to use a  tag, because it's not a full html document. I am using it in the same manner, but for some reason mine is not working. Can anybody help me with this? Is there something wrong with my CSS?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/23ktd8q6bdekhi8/scorix.css" />
```

EDIT: When someone links to this one, it works fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2uh6gphwjgmenu/betteralone.css?dl=1" />
```

Comment: give us an example of one that works.

Comment: I pasted the link to your CSS in my browser and that's not a valid CSS file because it's in an HTML container (when you view the source of the page, you see HTML code)... That's why is not working.  You need to link to an actual CSS page for your code to work.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to know what needs to be fixed. Thanks for just pointing out the useless Vash

Comment: why is it useless? you're here asking for help.  It's obvious you weren't capable of spotting the reason why it's not working, _I_ pointed it out.

Comment: What he's saying is, you need a direct link to the CSS, that dropbox link isn't actually a css file, it's dropbox displaying a css file.

Comment: Again, I already commented I found the problem. The only difference between the two links was the ?dl=1.

Answer (score 0):

The link should be a direct download link. This should work (at least, let's hope so):

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/23ktd8q6bdekhi8/scorix.css?dl=1&token_hash=AAFS1EYWJejOVo_PQ8c8RSK0rRbKC0kPt0fXEz5T7i5A7Q
```

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with your HTML link code and your CSS validates flawlessly.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work because if you past that link, you get prompted to download the file.  for it to work, you should be able to see the CSS in your browser

Comment: I found the problem. The only difference between the two links was this: 

    <link href=".css?dl=1">

Once I added that, problem solved.

Comment: @VashTheStampede http://jsfiddle.net/GM6Va/. Works in JFiddle, should work in real life.